# Websharper on mono

Tags: .net, f#, websharper

Simple question: Is it possible to host websharper applications on mono. If not, are there any plans to support such a feature?

Comment: This question should probably be directed to the mono team

Comment: In theory, yes. I remember trying once and encountering a single issue. I reported it and was told it'll be fixed in the next version, I think should work just find (it was quite a while ago).

Comment: Why don't you set this up and try it yourself?  I mean, seriously, what's stopping you?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I'd have also asked before trying (in fact, I did, though not here). This can take an hour or two of setting up, researching and configuring - it might not be worth it.

Comment: I would ask first too (after a cursory search on google of course :-) )

Comment: Thanks for the comments, i'm gonna try soon enough and answer my own question :)

Comment: +1 for the question, +1 for the answer when you post it.